# Solve the following Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose if we want to solve $\frac{d}{dx}u + f(x)u(x) = 0,$ then the solution is $u(x)=u(0)e^{-\int_0^xf(y)dy}$. Similarly what is the solution of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u- \frac{d}{dx}u - f(x)u(x) = 0,$ where $f(x)$ is a positive and bounded function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit solution known for generic (non-constant) $f$. Making the change $u(x)=e^{x/2}v(x)$, this equation transforms into $v''+\tilde{f}(x)v=0$, with $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)-\frac14$. If it were solvable, one would know, for example, the spectrum and eigenfunctions for any quantum-mechanical potential in one dimension. Alas, this is not the case.

Already for the simplest choice
$$f(x)=\frac{a+1-2b\cos x}{4}$$
the general solution is [expressed in terms of Mathieu functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve[y%27%27[x]+-+y%27[x]+%2B+%28%28a+%2B+1+-+2+b+Cos[x]%29%2F4%29+y[x]+%3D%3D+0%2C+y[x]%2C+x]).

Comment: One wrinkle that's interesting here: While there's generically not 'nice' solutions to $f(x)=a+b \cos x$, there are examples with nice solutions if one includes a $c \cos 2x$ term as well. See [this paper](http://www.lboro.ac.uk/microsites/maths/research/preprints/papers10/10-20.pdf) for examples. (This requires the parameters to be precisely chosen, however, and so these are definitely exceptional cases.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite it as a vector $Y=(u,u')^t$ and solve $Y'=AY$ with $A$ a matrix. The general solution to that equation is then $Y=\exp(tA)Y_0$.

EDIT: To clarify, the system becomes
$\left( \begin{matrix}
        u  \\
        u' 
\end{matrix} \right )' = \left( \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1\\
        f(x) & 1
\end{matrix} \right ) \left( \begin{matrix}
        u  \\
        u' 
\end{matrix} \right )$

More info from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Systems_of_Linear_Differential_Equations)

Comment: I think it won't work, because $f$ is a function of $x$, its not constant.

Comment: @Bhargav : I have edited my post, you can check wikipedia. There is no "easy" formula, as you have to compute the exponential of a matrix (nothing fun there), but the problem is well known.